# Scatter plot for a matrix of a given form

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, matrix, matplotlib

Suppose I have a matrix of the form where first column is all x points, the second column is all y points, and then the third and fourth are indicator variables telling whether the point belongs to a particular 'cluster' (can be either 1 or 0; so if in column 3 I have 1 for a third row, it means that the point of the third row, belongs to say cluster 1, which is represented by column 3).

My question is, how do I create a figure, scatter plot all the points belonging to cluster 1 and then on the same plot have scatter of the remaining points in another color. In Matlab, I would just say `figure`, then `hold on` and write out my commands. I am new to plotting in Python and not sure how this would be performed.

EDIT:

I think I made it work. How would I however, change marker size, depending on which cluster the point belongs to

Comment: Probably easiest to use logical indexing on the indicator variables to subset the required data points and then use scatter's marker property selectors while calling on each subset.

Comment: Matplotlib has a very similar interface to Matlab by design. You can do `pyplot.hold(True)`

Comment: I like how people that didn't do any real research have a tendency to prefix their questions with "I did research".

Comment: @MadPhysicist hahaha yes... but I found this to be a (sort of) interesting question and I wanted to flex my `matplotlib` muscles.

Comment: Every minute is costly. Why do research (actually I did do research, but as i said, a very quick one) if there are helpful people that can answer the question instantly?

Comment: It's a two way street. I answered quickly, and you can return the favour by looking at my answer and accepting it. You'll do the world a service. :)

Comment: I definitely will. I did not have time to look at it yet, that is why I have not accepted it just yet.

Comment: Ah I see no problem. I see you've accepted it though. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: thank you ray for the swift response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with how we'd do this in MATLAB.

Supposing you have `N` unique clusters, you can simply loop through as many clusters as you have and `plot` the points in a different colour.  Also, we can change the marker size at each iteration.  You'll need to use `logical` indexing to extract out the points that belong to each cluster.  Given that your matrix is stored in `M`, something like this comes to mind:

```
rng(123); %// Set random seeds
%// Total number of clusters
N = max(M(:,3));

%// Create a colour map
cmap = rand(N,3);

%// Store point sizes per cluster
sizes = [10 14 18];

figure; hold on; %// Create a blank figure and hold for changes

for ii = 1 : N
    %// Determine those points belonging to the ith cluster
    ind = M(:,3) == ii;

    %// Get the x and y coordinates
    x = M(ind,1);
    y = M(ind,2);

    %// Plot the points in a different colour
    plot(x,y,'.','Color', cmap(ii,:), 'MarkerSize', sizes(ii));
end

%// Create labels
labels = sprintfc('Label %d', 1:N);

%// Make our legend
legend(labels{:});
```

The code is pretty self explanatory, you need to define your matrix `M` and we determine the total number of clusters by taking the max of the third column.  Next we create a random colour map which has as many rows as there are clusters and there are three columns corresponding to a unique RGB colour per cluster.  Each row defines a colour for each cluster which we'll use when plotting.

Next we create an array of sizes where we store the radius of each point stored in an array per cluster.  We create a blank figure, hold it for changes we make to the plot then we iterate over each cluster of points.  For each cluster of points, figure out the right points in `M` to extract out through `logical` indexing, extract out the `x` and `y` coordinates for those points then plot these points on your figure in a scatter formation where we manually specify the colour as a RGB tuple as well as the desired marker size.

We then create a cell array of labels that denote which set of points each cluster belongs to, then show a legend illustrating which points belong to which clusters given this array of labels.

Generating random data with random labels, where we have 20 points uniformly distributed between `[0,1]` for both `x` and `y` and generating a random set of up to three labels:

```
rng(123);
M = [rand(20,2) randi(3,20,1)];
```

I get this plot when I run the above code:

[image]

---

To get the equivalent in Python, well that's pretty easy.  It's just a transcription from MATLAB to Python and the plotting mechanisms are exactly the same.  You're using `matplotlib` and so I'm assuming `numpy` can be used as it's a dependency.

As such, the equivalent code would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)

# Total number of clusters
N = int(np.max(M[:,2]))

# Create a colour map
cmap = np.random.rand(N, 3)

# Store point sizes per cluster
sizes = np.array([10, 14, 18]);

plt.figure(); # Create blank figure. No need to hold on

for ii in range(N):
    # Determine those points belonging to the ith cluster
    ind = M[:,2] == (ii+1)

    # Get the x and y coordinates
    x = M[ind,0];
    y = M[ind,1];

    # Plot the points in a different colour
    # Also add in labels for legend
    plt.plot(x,y,'.',color=tuple(cmap[ii]), markersize=sizes[ii], label='Cluster #' + str(ii+1))

# Make our legend
plt.legend()

# Show the image
plt.show()
```

I won't bother explaining this one because it's pretty much the same as what you see in the MATLAB code.  There are some nuances, such as the way `hold on` works in `matplotlib`.  You don't need to use `hold on` because any changes you make the figure will be remembered until you decide to show the figure.  You also have the nuances where `numpy` and Python start indexing at 0 instead of 1.

Using the same generation data code like in MATLAB:

```
M = np.column_stack([np.random.rand(20,2), np.random.randint(1,4,size=(20,1))])
```

I get this figure:

[image]